# I can't get div id displayed in loop in Code Igniter

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, codeigniter

I have a command that creates a loop:

```
foreach($cart as $line=>$item).
```

When it displays, it shows the HTML quoted below. I have tried to add a div id below the loop, as I want to create a `getElementById()` function. However, it creates a loop above on its own. Also, I cannot change the tr statement. I have actually done a search and replace on every tr statement in Code Igniter and it is still there. I am quite a novice, and would really appreciate any advice, as this has been baffling me for three days now.

```
    <tbody id="cart_contents">
<?php
if(count($cart)==0)
{
?>

<tir><td colspan='8'>
<div class='warning_message' style='padding:7px;'><?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_no_items_in_cart'); ?></div>
</tr></tr>



    <?php
}
else
{
    echo "</tr><tir>";

        foreach($cart as $line=>$item)
    {


    ?>


        <td id = " <?php echo $item['name'];?>" style="align:center;" ><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>



        <?php if ($items_module_allowed)
        {

        ?>
            <td><?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6'));?></td>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
            <?php echo form_hidden('price',$item['price']); ?>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <td>
        <?php
            if($item['is_serialized']==1)
            {
                echo $item['quantity'];
                echo form_hidden('quantity',$item['quantity']);
            }
            else
            {
                echo form_input(array('name'=>'quantity','value'=>$item['quantity'],'size'=>'2'));
            }
        ?>
        </td>

        <td><?php echo to_currency($item['price']*$item['quantity']-$item['price']*$item['quantity']*$item['discount']/100); ?></td>

        <?php
            if($item['allow_alt_description']==1)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                if ($item['description']!='')
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        ?>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="color:#2F4F4F";>
        <?php
            if($item['is_serialized']==1)
            {
            }
        ?>
        </td>
        <td colspan=3 style="text-align:left;">
        <?php
            if($item['is_serialized']==1)
            {
            }
        ?>
        </td>


        </tr>
        <tr style="height:3px">
        <td colspan=8 style="background-color:white"> </td>
        </tr>       </form>
    <?php
    }


}
?>
</tbody>
</table>        </div>
```

This is the HTML output from the original loop.

```
<tr><td id=" test" style="align:center;">test</td>

    <td><input type="text" name="price" value="150.00" size="6"></td>

    <td>
        etc...
    </td>


</tr>
```

Comment: Could you post the whole of the loop, please?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have just updated the php code above. regards, simon

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what is the problem? What is it (not) doing and what is it supposed to?

Comment: Hi Czechnology. When I put a div statement within the loop, ( I want it to create a div id with the item number as the id), it appears above the loop. I just cant get anything in the loop. I am wondering if this is some setting with codeigniter. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe your problem is with your php, I think it is your html.

Your html opening and closing tags do not all match up.  You have several unclosed `<tr>` elements, at least one un-opened `<tr>`, your form tags don't work out given your if/else statement structure, and you don't actually have an opening `<table>` tag or an opening `<div>` tag at the top of your code while you have both at the end.  The div that you are getting above your loop that you expect to occur IN your loop is probably the result of your browser trying to interpret the broken page structure.

As far as the form tags I mentioned, make sure that if you use an if statement to open a form, you must also have a condition that will open any required forms if the if statement evaluates to false.  I think you have a form element inside an if, then form inputs as part of the next else statement.

I've simplified your posted code and included comments to try and illustrate this:

```
    <tbody id="cart_contents">
<?php if(){?>
    <tir><!--what's a 'tir'?, did you mean 'tr'?-->
        <td colspan='8'>
            <div class='warning_message' style='padding:7px;'>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </tr>
<?php }else{
    echo "</tr><tir>";//here you are closing a row that was never opened, and another 'tir'.  
    foreach($cart as $line=>$item){?>
            <td></td>
            <?php if (){ //here you call a form input before the form is created...?>
                <td><?php echo form_input();?></td>
                <?php }else{?>
                 <td></td>
                <?php echo form_hidden(); 
                //this form isn't in a table element, which might act weird?>
            <?php }?>
            <td><?php if() {
                    echo form_hidden();
                }else{
                    echo form_input());
                    //here you have a form input outside of a form if 
                    //the previous if statement evaluates to false.
                }?>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <?php if(){ }
            else {
                if(){}
                else{}
            }?>
        </td><!--this td was never opened-->
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr><!--this tr was never opened-->
    <tr><td></td></tr>      
  </form><!--I don't believe you can count on your conditional statements to garantee that a form was opened-->
    <?php }
    } ?>
</tbody>
</table> <!--you haven't opened your table in this code-->
</div><!--you havent' opened a div in this code-->
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found a way of displaying the divs by just recreating the loop again. I think there is something that the script was calling that altered the structure. My problem now is that i have gave every form element an id, and I want to call it by get document by id. It isnt working. is there an easy way of doing this.